Reusable modal fragment thymeleaf
I am trying to reuse the following modal (as a fragment) with thymeleaf.
<th:block th:fragment="modalFragment (modalId, labelId, modalTitle, formId, saveButtonId, fields)">
    <div class="modal fade" th:id="${modalId}" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
         th:aria-labelledby="${labelId}" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" th:id="${labelId}" th:text="${modalTitle}">Título del Modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Renderizar el formulario solo si formId no es null -->
                        <form th:if="${formId != null and formId != ''}" th:id="${formId}" class="row g-3">
                            <!-- Espacio reservado para campos del formulario dinámicos, definidos en la página de inclusión -->
                            <th:block th:replace="~{this :: fields}"></th:block>
                        </form>
                        <!-- Renderizar contenido alternativo si formId es null -->
<!--                        <th:block th:unless="${formId != null}" th:replace="~{this :: fields}"></th:block>-->
                        <th:block th:unless="${formId != null and formId != ''}">
                            <th:block th:replace="~{this :: fields}"></th:block>
                        </th:block>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <!-- Renderizar el botón de guardar solo si saveButtonId está definido -->
                    <button type="button" th:if="${saveButtonId != null and saveButtonId != ''}" th:id="${saveButtonId}"
                            class="btn btn-custom">Guardar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</th:block>

When I use it this way in my .html it works without problems.
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/modalFragment :: modalFragment(
    modalId='modalUsuario',
    labelId='staticBackdropLabelUsuario',
    modalTitle='Usuario',
    formId='formularioRegistroUsuario',
    saveButtonId='btnGuardarUsuario',
    fields='~{this :: fields}')}">
        <!-- Campos del formulario definidos directamente dentro de la inclusión del modal -->
        <th:block th:fragment="fields">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-6 d-none">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuId" name="usuId" placeholder="Id"
                           readonly>
                    <label for="usuId">Id</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <select class="form-select componente-select" id="usuActivo" name="usuActivo"
                            aria-label="Estado"
                            data-lista="1" data-lista-idioma="1" required>
                        <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="usuActivo">Estado</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Usamos este div vacío para forzar que la siguiente columna que haya después vaya abajo. -->
            <div class="w-100 m-0"></div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <select class="form-select componente-select" id="roles"
                            aria-label="Rol"
                            data-live-search="true" data-url="buscarListaRoles">
                        <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="roles">Rol</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <select class="form-select componente-select"
                            id="sistemas"
                            aria-label="Sistemas"
                            data-url="buscarListaSistemas"
                            title="Selecciona una opción"
                            data-live-search="true" data-size="8" multiple
                            data-actions-box="true">
                    </select>
                    <label for="sistemas">Sistemas</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuUsuario" name="usuUsuario"
                           placeholder="Usuario" required>
                    <label for="usuUsuario">Usuario</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Usamos este div vacío para forzar que la siguiente columna que haya después vaya abajo. -->
            <div class="w-100 m-0"></div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating d-flex align-items-center bg-white">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control"
                           id="usuPassword" name="usuPassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    <label for="usuPassword">Contraseña</label>
                    <span><i id="btnMostrarPass"
                             class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill cursor-pointer"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating d-flex align-items-center bg-white">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control"
                           id="usuRepitePassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    <label for="usuRepitePassword">Repite contraseña</label>
                    <span><i id="btnMostrarRepitePass"
                             class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill cursor-pointer"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="mensajeMayusculas" class="col-12 text-center d-none">
                <i class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill me-2"></i>
                <span>El bloqueo de mayúsculas está activado</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuNombre" name="usuNombre"
                           placeholder="Nombre" required>
                    <label for="usuNombre">Nombre</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuPrimerApellido" name="usuPrimerApellido"
                           placeholder="Primer apellido" required>
                    <label for="usuPrimerApellido">Primer apellido</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuSegundoApellido" name="usuSegundoApellido"
                           placeholder="Segundo apellido">
                    <label for="usuSegundoApellido">Segundo apellido</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuDni" name="usuDni"
                           placeholder="DNI">
                    <label for="usuDni">DNI</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuTelefono" name="usuTelefono"
                           placeholder="Teléfono">
                    <label for="usuTelefono">Teléfono</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usuEmail" name="usuEmail"
                           placeholder="Email">
                    <label for="usuEmail">Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </th:block>
    </div>

But when I want to add a second modal to the same .html it does not work as it should.
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/modalFragment :: modalFragment(
    modalId='modalUsuario2',
    labelId='staticBackdropLabelUsuario2',
    modalTitle='Usuario2',
    formId='',
    saveButtonId='',
    fields='~{this :: fields}')}">
        <!-- Campos del formulario definidos directamente dentro de la inclusión del modal -->
        <th:block th:fragment="fields">
          <p>HOLA</p>
        </th:block>
    </div>

What it does is to put me the same fields in both modals. In the second one they come out without layout maybe because they're repeated fields, I see the duplicated ids on the DevTools console.
I have tried to change:
fields='~{this :: fields}')}" with fields='~{this :: fields2}')}" and <th:block th:fragment="fields2"> but it doesn't work either.
Do you have any idea why it doesn't work? I guess it doesn't resolve the “this” context well or something like that.
¡EDIT!
I solved it doing this:
<th:block th:fragment="modalFragment (modalId, labelId, modalTitle, formId, saveButtonId, fields)">
<div class="modal fade" th:id="${modalId}" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
     th:aria-labelledby="${labelId}" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" th:id="${labelId}" th:text="${modalTitle}">Título del Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Renderizar el formulario solo si formId no es null -->
                    <form th:if="${formId != null and formId != ''}" th:id="${formId}" class="row g-3">
                        <!-- Espacio reservado para campos del formulario dinámicos, definidos en la página de inclusión -->
                        <th:block th:replace="~{this::${fields}}"></th:block>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Renderizar contenido alternativo si formId es null -->
                    <th:block th:unless="${formId != null and formId != ''}">
                        <th:block th:replace="~{this::${fields}}"></th:block>
                    </th:block>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <!-- Renderizar el botón de guardar solo si saveButtonId está definido -->
                <button type="button" th:if="${saveButtonId != null and saveButtonId != ''}" th:id="${saveButtonId}"
                        class="btn btn-custom">Guardar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></th:block>

And calling the fragment like this:
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/modalFragment :: modalFragment(
modalId='modalUsuario',
labelId='staticBackdropLabelUsuario',
modalTitle='Usuario',
formId='formularioRegistroUsuario',
saveButtonId='btnGuardarUsuario',
fields='camposModalUsuario')}">
    <!-- Campos del formulario definidos directamente dentro de la inclusión del modal -->
    <th:block th:fragment="camposModalUsuario">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-6 d-none">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuId" name="usuId" placeholder="Id"
                       readonly>
                <label for="usuId">Id</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <select class="form-select componente-select" id="usuActivo" name="usuActivo"
                        aria-label="Estado"
                        data-lista="1" data-lista-idioma="1" required>
                    <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                </select>
                <label for="usuActivo">Estado</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Usamos este div vacío para forzar que la siguiente columna que haya después vaya abajo. -->
        <div class="w-100 m-0"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <select class="form-select componente-select" id="roles"
                        aria-label="Rol"
                        data-live-search="true" data-url="buscarListaRoles">
                    <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                </select>
                <label for="roles">Rol</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <select class="form-select componente-select"
                        id="sistemas"
                        aria-label="Sistemas"
                        data-url="buscarListaSistemas"
                        title="Selecciona una opción"
                        data-live-search="true" data-size="8" multiple
                        data-actions-box="true">
                </select>
                <label for="sistemas">Sistemas</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuUsuario" name="usuUsuario"
                       placeholder="Usuario" required>
                <label for="usuUsuario">Usuario</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Usamos este div vacío para forzar que la siguiente columna que haya después vaya abajo. -->
        <div class="w-100 m-0"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating d-flex align-items-center bg-white">
                <input type="password" class="form-control"
                       id="usuPassword" name="usuPassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
                <label for="usuPassword">Contraseña</label>
                <span><i id="btnMostrarPass"
                         class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill cursor-pointer"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating d-flex align-items-center bg-white">
                <input type="password" class="form-control"
                       id="usuRepitePassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
                <label for="usuRepitePassword">Repite contraseña</label>
                <span><i id="btnMostrarRepitePass"
                         class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill cursor-pointer"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="mensajeMayusculas" class="col-12 text-center d-none">
            <i class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill me-2"></i>
            <span>El bloqueo de mayúsculas está activado</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuNombre" name="usuNombre"
                       placeholder="Nombre" required>
                <label for="usuNombre">Nombre</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuPrimerApellido" name="usuPrimerApellido"
                       placeholder="Primer apellido" required>
                <label for="usuPrimerApellido">Primer apellido</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuSegundoApellido" name="usuSegundoApellido"
                       placeholder="Segundo apellido">
                <label for="usuSegundoApellido">Segundo apellido</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuDni" name="usuDni"
                       placeholder="DNI">
                <label for="usuDni">DNI</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuTelefono" name="usuTelefono"
                       placeholder="Teléfono">
                <label for="usuTelefono">Teléfono</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usuEmail" name="usuEmail"
                       placeholder="Email">
                <label for="usuEmail">Email</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </th:block>
</div>

Basically I changed the way the call to the fragment references de fragment, and in the fragment, the way it uses the parameter fields.
Now, if I add a second modal, I just call the "fields" and the "fragment" different of the first one, and it works properly.
